# explain this css please

Tags: css

I am developing a css for printing **in IE8**, since i don't have advanced css selectors( http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/ ) i concatenate them like this

I need to modifiy certain columns in a table(e.g. make 8th column red, 9th longer, 10 shorter... ecc)

The question is if i use

```
td+td+td{ /*instead of td:nth-child(3) on modern browsers*/
 set something...
}
```

*all the td from the 3rd one to the last one have that "set something"*

so to fix it i have to do

```
td+td+td+td{
 unset something
}
```

So i fixed it, but wondering why it acts like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` denotes adjacent selectors.

`td+td { }` Generally means, if a `td` is preceded by another `td` then apply certain rule

One more example:

`a + p {}` Generally means, if `p` comes after `a` then apply certain rule.

So the style sheet you are using

`td+td+td` will apply the style to every `td` after the third elements. <sup>*This might be a little complicated to be clear about.*</sup> Lets see an example with sets of `<td>`

```
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
```

Your rule

```
td + td + td {
    /* apply something */
}
```

The above rule will apply to two different sets

1. First one, adjacent sibling from `<td>1</td>` to `<td>3</td>` matches `td+td+td`
2. Second one, adjacent sibling from `<td>2</td>` to `<td>4</td>` **also** matches `td+td+td`

So at the end, all the selectors from `<td>3</td>` end up getting the style

To cancel this effect, you reset the rule adding fourth selector on the style sheet.
i.e

```
td + td+ td + td {
  /* cancel the effect
  This will catch <td>-4</td> and apply the reset rule */
}
```

Hope that explains it.

---

## Further Reading

1. [W3 Org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)
2. [Good Explanation with examples](http://www.splashofstyle.com/archives/2006/07/18/css-child-adjacent-sibling-selectors/)
3. [One more to fully clarify](http://eriwen.com/css/css-adjacent-sibling-selectors/)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just put class names on the columns and style them directly? It eliminates multi-version hacks.

Answer (score 1):

`a + b` means: "select `b` if it is preceded by `a`".

`td+td+td` means: Select a `td` if it is preceded by 2 `<td>`s.

(see picture)
Every <kbd>X</kbd> is selected by `td+td+td`.
Every <kbd>Y</kbd> is selected by `td+td+td+td`.
To select the third sibling, both selectors has to be combined.

```
<td>  1        1                     = default
<td>  2 1      2 1                   = default
<td>  X 2 1    3 2 1   <--- X        = style X
<td>    X 2 1  Y 3 2   <--- X and Y  = style X, but reset to default by Y
<td>      X 2    Y 3   <--- X and Y  = style X, but reset to default by Y
<td>        X      Y   <--- X and Y  = style X, but reset to default by Y
```

Comment: sorry, didn't understood picture

Comment: @max4ever The numbers show that every element marked by X has 2 preceding siblings, and that every element marked by Y has 3 preceding siblings. At the right side, I've marked the outcome of the selectors. Now, do you understand the pic?